# Changing javascript to action all links with the same class not id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following snippit of code at the moment to change the links that have the id of #onelink to a different link (if altlink has content)

```
if ($("#onelink").length > 0) {
    if (altlink != '') {
        $("#onelink").attr('href', site_url + altlink);
    }
}
```

The html it is editing correctly is:

`<a href="http://www.website.com/default/" id="onelink">Update</a>`

Which it turns it into:

`<a href="http://www.website.com/testpage/" id="onelink">Update</a>`

It works good for a single id link, but in my case now I am using an id and there are 10+ links on the page.

I would assume this would work for a single link but it isn't:

```
if ($(".onelink").length > 0) {
    if (altlink != '') {
        $(".onelink").attr('href', site_url + altlink);
    }
}
```

The html it is editing **INCORRECTLY**:

`<a class="onelink otherclass otherclass other class" href="http://www.website.com/default/"><span class="button-text">Update</span></a>`

Which it turns into:

`<a class="onelink otherclass otherclass other class" href="http://www.website.comundefined"><span class="button-text">Update</span></a>`

`http://www.website.comundefined` should have come out as `http://www.website.com/testpage/`

Now as for multiple links I would have thought:

```
$(".onelink").each(function(){
    if ($(this).length > 0) {
        if (altlink != '') {
            $(this).attr('href', site_url + altlink);
        }
    }
});
```

But again, the same issue happens as above.

Comment: `altlink` does exist, I haven't included it but you can see from my post that I mentioned it works for a single link using an id, but as soon as I switch to class it fails.

Comment: Something is problem with altlink. That's the issue. Trust us, we know.

Comment: It's nothing to do with `altlink`, it's something to do with it struggling with the class. Compare https://jsfiddle.net/ctbxa1aL/ and https://jsfiddle.net/ctbxa1aL/1/ As you can see the first one runs correctly but second one doesn't.

Comment: @Ryflex Does my solution work for you? I have added a working fiddle too. `:)`

Comment: Always check the jsfiddle onload settings. If you use document.ready or such, change the setting to head instead of onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if `altlink` exists and it is not empty:

```
if (altlink && altlink.length > 0) {
```

So your full code will be:

```
$(".onelink").attr("href", function() {
    if (altlink && altlink.length > 0) {
        $(this).attr('href', site_url + altlink);
    }
});
```

And make sure to include jQuery and put this code under `$(document).ready()` function.

**Snippet**

```js
site_url = "http://facebook.com/";
altlink = "?search=praveen";
$(function () {
  $(".onelink").attr("href", function(){
    if (altlink && altlink.length > 0) {
      return site_url + altlink;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.onelink {background: #ccf;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="http://www.google.com/">Non Alt Link</a></div>
<div><a href="http://www.google.com/" class="onelink">Alt Link</a></div>
<div><a href="http://www.google.com/">Non Alt Link</a></div>
<div><a href="http://www.google.com/" class="onelink">Alt Link</a></div>
<div><a href="http://www.google.com/">Non Alt Link</a></div>
<div><a href="http://www.google.com/" class="onelink">Alt Link</a></div>
<div><a href="http://www.google.com/">Non Alt Link</a></div>
<div><a href="http://www.google.com/" class="onelink">Alt Link</a></div>
<div><a href="http://www.google.com/">Non Alt Link</a></div>
<div><a href="http://www.google.com/" class="onelink">Alt Link</a></div>
```

Comment: What does `if ($(this).length > 0) {` do?

Comment: @Tushar Ha ha. Nothing.